# Where to put Properties in MVC pattern

Tags: java, xml, design-patterns, model-view-controller, properties

If I have a class such as `ConfigReader` which is able to store data from XML or Properties, usually with an `initialize()` method and getters for every field, where am I most likely supposed to implement it when using a classic MVC pattern?

In my opinion it would be a controller. However, when working with console applications, the configuration could be an essential part to display data in the console, therefore a view as well.

Comment: I tend to create a separate service, which deals with reading and writing various configuration sources.

Comment: I would think settings would be part of the model, and views that rely on those settings would be subscribers to those settings change. I don't have much practical experience with MVC though.